# How to detect release of a keystroke using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, action, key-bindings

I am having some issues getting some code to work that detects release of a keystroke.  I am writing a video game, and I would like to iniitate the movement of an icon with the press of a key, and terminate the movement once the key has been released.  I have read other people's postings on this, and they seem to say the way to handle this is to set a flag in the keyReleased code that would terminate the movement I assume you would have initiated in the keyPressed code.  However, I assume you would have to put a Thread.Sleep into the KeyPressed code in order to allow the KeyReleased code to fire (which would set the flag)? Otherwise control would never return to the dispatch loop from the KeyPressed code?

Anyway, here is the code I can not get to work that should pickup the release of key 'a'.

MoveGunLeftActionReleased aKeyActionReleased= new MoveGunLeftActionReleased();

…

…

```
statusPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released a"), "aCharKeyReleased");

statusPanel.getActionMap().put("aCharKeyReleased", aKeyActionReleased);
```

…
…

```
static class MoveGunLeftActionReleased extends AbstractAction
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rf) {
        System.out.println("RELEASED");
        aKeyReleased= true;
    }
}
```

The object: aKeyActionReleased never executes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released a")
```

That is not the proper format. It should be:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A")
```

If you need more help post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that.  I made the 'a' uppercase.  The method still didn't fire.

Comment: @user1104028, and you didn't post a `SSCCE`, so how do you expect us to help based on 2 lines of code??? Does your component have focus? Maybe you are using the wrong `InputMap`. If you want help read the entire answer and provde the code we need to help solve the problem. We don't have time for 20 questions!!!

Comment: Ok, I know the inputMap is correct because it is working with all my other Keystroke KeyAction callbacks.  And I know there is no issue with regard to focus, because again all my other keyStroke events are working.  I thought I was having an issue with how I setup the code to capture the KeyRelease event.  So that is why I only posted 2 lines of the code.

Comment: I give up. That is NOT a SSCCE!!! How can we compile and execute that code? You are making a statement that the code doesn't work. Prove it. Post your demo code that tests the relevant functionality that you are asking about. The SSCCE should be about 20 lines of code. You create a frame, a component and add the key binding to the component.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what was wrong.  As you guys noted, I should have an uppercase A in the string expression.  But what was also causing a problem  was that I was also trying to detect just a regular press of the same key.  And for that I had utilized KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a') and it seems if I had that in there, then the call KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A") would not fire.  Not sure why it is like this (can't mix these things?), but I switched to what I needed anyway, which was to just detect the initial press.  Once I had added KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed A"), everything worked.